# Capture, display, and save webcam video with openCV using C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, image, opencv, video

The basics were taken from one of the more basic OpenCV examples.

Any comments are welcome regarding style and conventions, etc., as well as tips on using the OpenCV library, which I'm new to. Also, anyone who has attempted a project like this before (in any language) and has any tips that they wouldn't mind sharing this would be great.

My main problem at the minute is in the saveNoDisplay() function. This runs in its own std::thread, which is stopped and joined back to main after Esc and return are entered in the bash terminal. All of the other functions for displaying the video run in the main thread and quit as soon as Esc is pressed (no need for return). Is there a way I can remove the need for return in the std::thread?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

atomic_bool stop = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

string queryDisplayVid(string& displayOption) {
    cout << "Display? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> displayOption;
    return displayOption;
}

string querySaveVid(string& saveOption) {
    string filename;
    string extension = ".avi";
    cout << "Save? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> saveOption;
    if (saveOption == "Y") {
        cout << "Filename:" << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        filename = filename + extension;
        cout << "Saving the video to "
             << filename << endl;
    }
    else if (saveOption == "N") {
        cout << "Not saving the video." << endl;
    }
    return filename;
}

int displayNoSave() {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {        
        while(1) {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
            imshow("Frame", frame);
            char c = (char)waitKey(1);
            if (c == 27)
                break ;
        }
        cap.release();
        return 0;
    }
}

int displaySave(string filename) {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int frame_width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        int frame_height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        VideoWriter video(filename ,CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 10,
                          Size(frame_width,frame_height));
        while(1) {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
            video.write(frame);
            imshow("Frame", frame);
            char c = (char)waitKey(1);
            if (c == 27)
                break ;
        }
        cap.release();
        video.release();
        return 0;
    }
}

int saveNoDisplay(string filename) {
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int frame_width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
        int frame_height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
        VideoWriter video(filename ,CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 10,
                          Size(frame_width,frame_height));
        while(!stop) {
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
            video.write(frame);
            char c = (char)waitKey(1);
            if (c == 27)
                break;
        }
        cap.release();
        video.release();
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    string displayOption, saveOption, filename;
    displayOption = queryDisplayVid(displayOption);
    filename = querySaveVid(saveOption);
    if (displayOption == "Y" && saveOption == "N") {
        displayNoSave();
    }
    if (displayOption == "Y" && saveOption == "Y") {
        displaySave(filename);
    }
    if (displayOption == "N" && saveOption == "Y") {
        cout << "Capturing the video. Press Esc + enter to stop and save."
             << endl;
        thread workerThread(saveNoDisplay, filename);
        char c;
        while (true) {
            c = getchar();
            if (c == 27) {
                stop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        workerThread.join();
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -pthread -o `basename startCamCap.cpp .cpp` startCamCap.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```